# Whether the function system() can be invoked in a thread or not?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I want to use `system()` to execute a cmd.
If the cmd takes a long time like `ping`, it will block main thread.

So I want to create a child thread to handle it. In this child thread the `system()` will be invoked.

As we all know, the `system()` will fork a child process.
I'm NOT sure whether any problem or side effect when the `system()` is invoked in a child thread.

Comment: `system()` is multithreading-safe, as a quick glance into the manpage reveals.

Comment: on the contrary, a thread is perfect to perform this task.

It allows main processing to continue, and forking is performed from the thread, transparently by the `system` command. It still creates another process anyway, but no need to use `fork`.

Comment: You know exactly what `system` is doing (if you don't - the `man` page is describing it - it will `fork`, `execl` and `waitpid`). Write down this sequence and analyze it together with the rest of your program and decide if there are potential issues these two might create.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but *If the cmd takes a long time like `ping`*?  You're not going to actually do something like `ping` a server before you try do something like open a TCP connection to it for some reason, are you?  "Check X, if it works then do Y" is almost always a bad idea because X doesn't really tell you if Y would work.  Just *do* Y and handle any failure - you have to do that anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system()` is marked as thread-safe by Linux/glibc documentation. See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). But with a caveat:

> According to POSIX.1, it is unspecified whether handlers registered
>       using pthread_atfork(3) are called during the execution of system().
>       In the glibc implementation, such handlers are not called.

From what you described, you probably don't have atfork handlers, so it's fine.

> I want to use system() to execute a cmd. If the cmd takes a long time like ping, it will block main thread.

However, if the sole purpose of using a separate thread is to run a command, why not `fork(2)` directly and let it child process exec command?
The main process can still carry on and can check whether the child process completed (e.g., using [`waitpid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) with `WNOHANG`).
This would be cleaner in my opinion and avoids the fork+threads complexity.